# Update an array in an angular accordion panel

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

Below I have an an angular bootstrap accordion and I am trying to figure out how to properly scope an array to each accordion panel. For example, below I have an accordion and inside each panel, I print out an array called 'item'. The add item button adds a new item to the array and updates every panel. My question is, how would I only update the array in the panel where I clicked on the config button and not update the arrays in the other panels? Do I need to create an instance of the items array for each panel?

```
<accordion>
<accordion-group ng-repeat="product in postcodelist">
    <accordion-heading>
        {{product}}
    </accordion-heading>
    <a ng-click="addItem()">Add item</a>
    {{items}}
</accordion-group>
```

```
$scope.items = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];

$scope.addItem = function() {
var newItemNo = $scope.items.length + 1;
$scope.items.push('Item ' + newItemNo);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do think that you need to create an instance of the items array for each panel. Otherwise everything will become confusing at the end.
My modification:

```
<accordion>
<accordion-group ng-repeat="product in postcodelist">
    <accordion-heading>
        {{product}}
    </accordion-heading>
    <a ng-click="addItemToProduct($index)">Add item</a>        
    {{itemsOfProduct[product]}}
</accordion-group>
```

and the script:

```
$scope.postcodelist = ['post01','post02','post03'];

$scope.itemsOfProduct = {};

$scope.addItemToProduct = function(index) {
    var newItemNo;
    $scope.itemsOfProduct[$scope.postcodelist[index]] = $scope.itemsOfProduct[$scope.postcodelist[index]] || [];
    newItemNo = $scope.itemsOfProduct[$scope.postcodelist[index]].length + 1;

    $scope.itemsOfProduct[$scope.postcodelist[index]].push('Item ' + newItemNo);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should really be using a directive for this use case. Please review the Angularjs documentation for Directives (https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive).

But something such as

```
angular.module('plunker').

directive('accordianBody', [function() {

    var accordianBodyCtrl = function($scope) {  
        $scope.addElement = function(newElement) {
            $scope.accordianArray.push('Item ' + newElement);
        };
    };

    return {
       restrict: 'E',
           scope: {
               accordianArray:"="
           },
           templateUrl: 'my_accordian_body',
           controller: ['$scope', accordianBodyCtrl],
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
           }
      };
}]);
```

This directive would allow you to specify your html as follows

```
<accordion>
    <accordion-group ng-repeat="product in postcodelist">

    <accordion-heading>
        {{product}}
    </accordion-heading>
    <accordian-body accordian-array="items"></accordian-body>
</accordion-group>
```

where `items` is the array to update for each accordian panel. You will need an parent controller which somehow organizes all of your seperate arrays. You have not specified any logic for the use case.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't have to create multiple array you can use them though panels just define it over the panels' scope and initiate them so they wont initiate their own array when they cant find one